# Sessions are expiring prematurely

Tags: php, session, cookies

My sessions are expiring prematurely. I'm not sure if this is due to a misconfiguration in my `php.ini` file; or if it is something else on my server. They expire within around 45-60 minutes of creation.

I'm running:

- nginx 1.4.6
- PHP 5.5.9
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

When I check the session cookie in the browser, it says that it expires when the browser session ends; however it always expires prematurely.

My `php.ini` file also says that my `session.cookie_lifetime = 0`, which means that sessions will expire when the browser closes. The rest of my session configuration in `php.ini` can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/cM2PggLt).

How can I troubleshoot and solve this? I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PHP is configured to cleanup session files after 30 minutes of inactivity

`; After this number of seconds, stored data will be seen as 'garbage' and
; cleaned up by the garbage collection process.
; http://php.net/session.gc-maxlifetime
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1800`

Comment: I will give it a shot and let you know how it goes, thanks!